# Find on MongoDb, multi document values into one document

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, php-mongodb, database

I would like to extract a list of ean from my MongoDB database.
With "find ()" I get separate documents. I would like to get a list of ean in a unique view of the document, or at most in an array.
I know that I could read the data in php and process them.
But since I'm learning to use MongoDB and "MongoDB Driver" for PHP I would like to understand how to extract data directly from the database using commands.

My DB:

```
{
   "_id" : "ID0001",
   "ean" : [ 
       "4960999612638", 
       "4960999150437",
       "0050332160514"
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : "ID0002",
   "ean" : [ 
       "4960999213743"
   ]
}
{
    "_id" : "ID0003",
    "ean" : [ 
        "0050332143265", 
        "0050332143258"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "ID0004",
    "ean" : [ 
        "0050332160514"
    ]
}
```

What I would like to get (or similar):

```
{
   "ean" : [
      "4960999612638"
      "4960999150437"
      "0050332160514"
      "4960999213743"
      "0050332143265"
      "0050332143258"
   ]
}
```

I would also delete duplicate ean by the results, but that's another story...

I can do this with mongodb?

Thanks to all those want help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using distinct function. I am not very familiar with php but I think, the code would look like that:

```
$collection->distinct("ean");
```

Comment: Perfect! It 'just what I needed!
db.getCollection('products').distinct("ean")
Thank you very much!